# How to get cell value from gridview when radio button list item is selected?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which is displaying data dynamically from SQL table. No problem with this part. I've added a colunm that contains a radio button list. I would like to get all cells value of Column 3 (index 2) if a radio button list item of these rows is selected when the user click on the Submit button.

My gridview :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        RadioButtonList
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="Radio1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="OK" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="KO" />
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Click"/>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strSQLconnection = "Connection to DB";
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection);

    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Champ1, Champ2, Camp3 FROM Table1 WHERE Condition1 IS NULL AND Condition2 IS NULL", sqlConnection);

    sqlConnection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

    GridView1.DataSource = reader;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Edit : Gridview example

```
---------------------------------------------
Radio   | Column0   | Column1   | Column2   |
---------------------------------------------
°OK °KO | abc       | abc       | abc       |
---------------------------------------------
°OK °KO | abc       | abc       | abc       |
--------------------------------------------- 
°OK °KO | abc       | abc       | abc       |
--------------------------------------------- 
°OK °KO | abc       | abc       | abc       |
--------------------------------------------- 
°OK °KO | abc       | abc       | abc       |
--------------------------------------------- 
°OK °KO | abc       | abc       | abc       |
--------------------------------------------
```

If a radio list item is selected, i would like to get value of the corresponding cell in column1 when clicking on submit button.

My code behind :

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    //Find the Radio button control
    RadioButtonList rb = (RadioButtonList)row.FindControl("Radio1");

    if (rb.SelectedItem.Text == "OK")
    {

        string id = row.Cells[2].Text;

        string query = "Query";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection to DB");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        con.Open();
        added = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
    }
}
}
```

The error faced when submitting :

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   MasterPage.Submit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +202
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +114
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +139
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +28
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2980
```

Dot know how to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the answer (and my comment) given by "Selva TS"

You have two issues, as Selva pointed out you should be validating that the RadioButtonList Selected item is not null before using it. Doing so will stop your error but will still not resolve the issue, the issue that you have is that the Page_Load is firing and re-binding your grid view which has the effect of resetting your radio button list.

To get around this change your Page_Load to

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!isPostBack)
     {
        string strSQLconnection = "Connection to DB";
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection);

        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Query", sqlConnection);

        sqlConnection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        GridView1.DataSource = reader;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

This will only bind the gridview if it is on the first load of the page (or it it is refreshed) not if one of the controls causes a postback.

You then need to amend the submit click as shown by Selva

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
  {
    //Find the Radio button control
      RadioButtonList rb = (RadioButtonList)row.FindControl("Radio1");
      if (rb.SelectedItem != null)
      {
          if (rb.SelectedItem.Text == "OK")
           {
              string id = row.Cells[2].Text;
              string query = "Query";

              SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection to DB");
              SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

              con.Open();
              added = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

              con.Close();
          }
      }
    }
 }
```

Doing JUST the page_load change will likely resolve the issue itself - but really you should be checking the SelectedItem for null just in case anyway! - Users can be fools and you should always try to anticipate their foolishness!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if you are not selected any `RadioButton`, the `SelectedItem` is always `null`. Just add one more validation in `RadioButton` control whether `SelectedItem` is `null` or not.

Adding `if (rb.SelectedItem != null)` condition in your code before validating `SelectedItem` will work,

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
      {
        //Find the Radio button control
          RadioButtonList rb = (RadioButtonList)row.FindControl("Radio1");
          if (rb.SelectedItem != null)
          {
              if (rb.SelectedItem.Text == "OK")
               {
                  string id = row.Cells[2].Text;
                  string query = "Query";

                  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection to DB");
                  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

                  con.Open();
                  added = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                  con.Close();
              }
          }
      }
   }
```

Also, as [d3vy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/993739/d3vy) suggested, adding  `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` in `Page_Load` will stop wiping the `SelectedItem` in the `RadioButtonList`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
      string strSQLconnection = "Connection to DB";
      SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection);

      SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Query", sqlConnection);

      sqlConnection.Open();

      SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

      GridView1.DataSource = reader;
      GridView1.DataBind();

      sqlConnection.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: You are correct, however there is a second issue here - the gridview bind is happening on page load and will be wiping the selectedItem property of the RadioButton list.

As well as the above you should have 

    if (!isPostBack)
    {
        //Your binding code here
    }

Otherwise when the page load is hit you will lose the selectedItem from the radio button list.

Hope that makes sense - its been a while since I used web forms, but have been tripped up by the same issue several times!

Comment: @D3vy Thats also the possible scenario.

Comment: I've added your two suggestions, but still getting the same error

Comment: Add a breakpoint to 
`RadioButtonList rb = (RadioButtonList)row.FindControl("Radio1");`
What is the value of `rb`? is it null or has it managed to locate the control?

Comment: @Shnabr what you are trying to get using this string id = row.Cells[2].Text;? There is no Cells[2] in your GridView. Please check that part.

Comment: @SelvaTS i'm trying to get the value of each rows in the column 1 of my gridview when a radio button is selected. The first colum is Radio and other one are Column  1, 2, 3 getting from my SQL query.

Comment: @Shnabr can you please validate each of the Cell exists before getting data from it?

Comment: @SelvaTS i would like to do so but i'm pretty new to C#. What's the correct syntax to get the value of each cells ? Maybe i'm just wrong with this part of code.

Comment: @SelvaTS i've added the query to let you know what i'm retrieving from my SQL database to display in the gridview.

Comment: @Shnabr try with row.Cells[1].Text;

Comment: @SelvaTS, sorry my bad. Cell in Column1 so i guess it's Cells[2] but still same issue.

Comment: @Shnabr where is your error pops actually? Put break point         string id = row.Cells[2].Text;
in this line and see what is the id.

Comment: @D3vy rb is not null and rbu.SelectedItem has the correct value (OK or KO)

Comment: @SelvaTS id is also not nul and has the correct value

Comment: @all thank you for your help, i was missing these two statements and also getting wrong with my sql query. My issue is resoled but how to just reload the page after these actions ?

Comment: Button click event automatically reloads the page.

Comment: @SelvaTS No i had to use Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)

Answer (score 0):

Had almost a similar problem, used input instead of `asp:radiobutton`:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select One">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <input name="MyRadioButton" type="radio" 
                value='<%# Eval("CategoryID") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then on `buttonClick` use request.form to get the value of selected `radiobutton`. If not selected it would return null.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string selectedValue = Request.Form["MyRadioButton"];
  lblMsg.Text = selectedValue;
}
```

Here is the link for more info:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13050/RadioButtons-inside-a-GridView-control